# Dialog fragment data binding leak memory

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

My Dialog Fragment keeping memory leak despite i already set `binding = null` in override of onDestroyView.
Here is my onCreateView and onDestroyView:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddressDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentAddressDialogBinding? = null
    private val viewModel: AddressViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_address_dialog, container, false)
        binding?.viewModel = viewModel
        binding?.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        // doing my things
        val view =  binding?.root
        return view!!
    }
}
```

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    binding = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

I use Navigation Component to navigate to this DiaLogFragment but don't think it a problem.
I have used the `binding.unbind()`, or `dismiss()` the DialogFragmet but it has no use.
I also checked that the DialogFragment already call to onDestroyView and onDestroy.

This is the leak i got from LeakCanary (2 leak on 1 time open and close the dialog, but just 1 distinct leak):

```
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static AccessibilityManager.sInstance
│                                  ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 374.7 kB in 8787 objects
│    ↓ AccessibilityManager.mTouchExplorationStateChangeListeners
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.ArrayMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 374.4 kB in 8775 objects
│    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
│               ~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 374.4 kB in 8773 objects
│    ↓ Object[0]
│            ~~~
├─ com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate$7 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 14.9 kB in 264 objects
│    Anonymous class implementing android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$TouchExplorationStateChangeListener
│    ↓ DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate$7.this$0
│                                    ~~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 14.9 kB in 263 objects
│    context instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.example.aposs_buyer.
│    uicontroler.activity.AddressActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ EndIconDelegate.textInputLayout
│                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View detached yet still part of window view hierarchy)
│    Retaining 12.4 kB in 298 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.example.aposs_buyer.
│    uicontroler.activity.AddressActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ View.mParent
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (TextInputLayout↑ is leaking and View detached yet still part of window view hierarchy)
│    Retaining 157.8 kB in 3879 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper, wrapping
│    activity com.example.aposs_buyer.uicontroler.activity.AddressActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ View.mParent
╰→ androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView instance
Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.aposs_buyer.uicontroler.fragment.
AddressDialogFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to
prevent leaks) and View detached yet still part of window view hierarchy)
Retaining 39.2 kB in 782 objects
key = 3588963a-7778-4442-ac60-a99f5380ede0
watchDurationMillis = 281964
retainedDurationMillis = 276959
View is part of a window view hierarchy
View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
mContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper, wrapping
activity com.example.aposs_buyer.uicontroler.activity.AddressActivity with mDestroyed = false
```

I hope i will got the answer soon. I have stuck with this leak for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out that it's the leak from TextInputLayout of the Materials Design library.
All i need todo to fix it is update Materials Design from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'`
The relate link helps me figure it out is here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2615

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here you should call `dismiss()` method in `onPause()` or in `onDestroy()` method. Depends on your requirement else it will create a memory leaks as the instance of bottomSheetFragment remains active.